# Magento 2 A customer website ID must be specified when using the website scope Error

Tags: customer, magento-2.2.5

I am getting this error while loading customer by mail `A customer website ID must be specified when using the website scope.`

Here is my code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');

    $CustomerModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer');
    $CustomerModel->setStoreId($storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId());
    //$this->setWebsiteId($storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
    $CustomerModel->setWebsiteId( $storeManager->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId());
```

Comment: Where are you running this code?

Comment: use below one,

$CustomerModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer');
$CustomerModel->setWebsiteId(1);
$CustomerModel->loadByEmail($customerEmail);
$userId = $CustomerModel->getId();

Answer (score 1):

So You can use the below code in this way. I have mentioned both the ways, so use any one to get customer model

```
public function __construct(
 \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $modelCustomer,
  \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
){
 $this->modelCustomer = $modelCustomer;
 $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
}

public function getCustomer()
   {
      $email = abc@gmail.com;
      $model = $this->modelCustomer->setWebsiteId(null)->loadByEmail($email);

    //or if you want get based on website id then,

      $websiteId =$this->storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
      $model = $this->modelCustomer->setWebsiteId( $websiteId)->loadByEmail($email);


    return $model;

}
```

Hope it will help you,Happy Coding!!